# Neo4J Nodes and Relationships : Do I have to model everything as a Node?

Tags: neo4j, relationship, nodes, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to use Neo4J with Spring Data, but I am not sure if my design is correct (First time I use a graph database).
The problem is that I don't know if I should model everything as a Node or just a simple attribute.

Example : (My biggest node)

```
@NodeEntity
public class User{

@Indexed(unique=true)
private String username;
@Indexed(unique=true)
private String email;

// Is a node ???
private Location location

private int areaRadius;

//No need to create a rich relationship
@RelatedTo(type=RelationshipTypes.LIKES, direction=Direction.OUTGOING)
@Fetch
private Set<Hobby> hobbies = new HashSet<Hobby>;

//No need to create a rich relationship
@RelatedTo(type=RelationshipTypes.HAS_CATEGORY, direction=Direction.OUTGOING, elementClass=Category.class)
@Fetch
private Set<Category> favCategories = new HashSet<Category>;

//Must create a rich relationship (Friendship.java)
@RelatedTo(type=RelationshipTypes.FRIEND_OF, direction=Direction.BOTH)
@Fetch
private Set<User> friends = new HashSet<User>;

//Rich relationship between Users (Friendship.java)
@RelatedToVia(type=RelationshipTypes.FRIEND_OF)
@Fetch
private Set<Friendship> friendships = new HashSet<Friendship>;

//Must create a rich relationship (UserEvent.java)
@RelatedTo(type=RelationshipTypes.GOING_TO, direction=Direction.OUTGOING)
@Fetch
private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<Event>;

//Rich relationship between Users (UserEvent.java)
@RelatedToVia(type=RelationshipTypes.GOING_TO)
@Fetch
private Set<UserEvent> userEvents = new HashSet<UserEvent>;

// Is a node ???
private Set<Status> statusList;

private URI profilePicture;

public User(){}

public User(String username, String email, Location location){
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.location = location;
}

public void addHobby(Hobby hobby){
    this.hobbies.add(hobby);
}

public void sendFriendRequestTo(User user){
    this.friendships.add(new Friendship(this, user, Friendship.REQUESTED);
}

public void addCategory(Category category){
    this.favCategories.add(category);
}

public void addConfirmedEvent(Event event){
    this.userEvents.add(new UserEvent(this, event, false));
}

public void addMaybeEvent(Event event){
    this.userEvents.add(new UserEvent(this, event, true);
}

}
```

My questions are :

1) Do I have to model the Status and the Location as Nodes ?

- Status will have : `String text, Set<String> tags, Date date`
- Location will have : `country, city, postalCode, double[] coordinates.`

2) I don't understand exactly how to store the related nodes with Spring Data :

- Do I need to store ONLY the relationships with `@RelatedToVia`
- Or Do I need to store ONLY the related nodes with `@RelatedTo`
- Or do I need to store BOTH

3) When I add a liked movie, how do I have to do it :

- Add it in the `likedMovies Set` ? (the relationship will be automatically created ?)
- Add it in the `relationship Set` (ratings for example) ? (then the likedMovies Set will be automatically updated in the next fetch)
- Add it in both ?

4) For the friends Set and the friendships Set, do I have to specify the same type (`type =` ) ?

EDIT :

NEW QUESTION :

5) If I have same relationships but with different @StartNodes (User has categories, but Movie also have a category). Do I have to create 2 @RelationshipEntity with the different @StartNode ? (it is not a rich relationship in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you should only model what is really an entity, like Venue with a location field. 
   Location makes sense if you connect more to it.
2. It depends on your model, if you have really rich relationships, you *can* use `@RelatedToVia` but you don't have to. See your entities rather as projections of certain use-cases, not the "one size fits all" which will bite you in the end.
3. If you have rich relationships you should add them to the @RelatedToVia Set. For a faster approach you can also use `template.createRelationshipBetween()`. Or just create the RelationshipEntity, assign start end end-node and properties and save it with `template.save()`.
4. yes, same relationship-type in the annotation
5. Do you have a "rich" relationship to the category? If not you don't have to model it. If yes, what would it look like? Then perhaps different types of category relationships make sense (also with different rel-types)
6. It depends on your model and your use-cases
   Remove the `@Fetch` annotations wherever possible it will just load a lot of data, that you might not need. Use `template.fetch(user.field)` if needed.
7. For many use-cases I recommend not loading and hydrating full entities from the database but instead running a query and projecting the minimum amount of data returned into a list of view objects/dto's with (annotated or derived) repository methods and `@QueryResult` on a POJO

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answers are clear. But I'm still a little confused about 5) : What I did now is the following :
@RelatedTo(type="HAS_CATEGORY")private Category category; for 2 or 3 different nodes.
And for the category node, I did this for each incoming nodes :
@RelatedTo(type=RelationshipTypes.HAS_CATEGORY, direction=Direction.INCOMING, enforceTargetType=true) Set<NodeWithCategory> nodes; I read that in the Spring Doc, is this the correct way ?

Comment: That's one way of doing it, but it is not very efficient. As it has to check the target type of the end node when loading the data.

Comment: So what do you suggest ? Creating different relationship types even if they describe the same relationship ?
By the way, your refcard is awesome, thanks.